# Requesting rest API generated using Swagger but it is giving me error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I am building web REST API using swagger with all its APIs. I am doing using Maven, I have included all the dependencies. When I clean install the project it does not give me any error, when I run it on Tomcat7 it executes all the code at sever API (as I can see it with console) but somewhere it fails and gives two lines of error

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
>   SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class io.swagger.model.User, genericType=class io.swagger.model.User.

I am not able to understand even though my project gets successful build, why it is not giving me that error and respond as

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Look into Server log and search for a stacktrace for more informations

Comment: Question is quite generic. Please provide more information such as logs or code samples.